# factor $x^2+1-6x^{-2}$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I'm trying to factor 
$$
x^2+1-6x^{-2}
$$
I don't know how to handle the $$x^{-2}$$ while having to get $$x^2$$ this is the best i can get
$$
(x+3)(x-2)
$$
is there exponent property or algebra property I should look for, so that i can get the answer?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  $x^2+1-6x^{-2}=(x^4+x^2-6)/x^2=(x^2+3)(x^2-2)/x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+1-6x^{-2}=(x^4+x^2-6)/x^2=(x^2+3)(x^2-2)/x^2$

Comment: oh wow thank you very much!